# AVAudioSequencer crashes without any debug information

Tags: debugging, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have an iOS app using AVAudioEngine. Among other components, I use an AVAudioSequencer to play MIDI files. Usually it works pretty well, but some MIDI files cause the player crashing at some point during playback (for a given file the crash happens always at the same point, so it it a deterministic error). This may be due to some wrong pre-processing I do on the MIDI file, but the problem is that the debugger does not report any information and there's no way to understand what happened.
My question is: does anybody knows how to receive some callback or to set up an error handler if an AVAudioSequencer crashes during playback? As far as I understand, it runs in background and there's no way to keep track of what it is doing...
Thanks a lot in advance to anyone can help!

Comment: not even a backtrace in the debugger?

Comment: Nothing appears in the debug window... I don't know if there is any other place I could look for a debug log. Indeed, it is not completely true that the player crashes. In noticed that it exits unexpectedly before the end of the file, but the app remains alive.The problem is that I cannot detect the early exit and then it remains in a wrong state, so that any other action I do causes a real crash. Difficult to explain, I hope I was clear enough....